# Copy database data from one database to another php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

In my database when I use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` I get result as `6639276`. Those data I want to save to another database. What I did is I used select then insert the data into the new database. It works well when I put `LIMIT 10`. Now when I remove the `LIMIT` part so that I can insert all the data into the new database I get `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

I am assuming because the data is too big.  How to work with big data for searching and inserting into a database?

#### Additional Info:

Reason why I need to use select / insert because the columns are not same. I need to select a column from database1 and set where to insert it in database2.

**Looping**:

```
$limit = 10000;

for($i = 0 ; $i < $stmt1count_row["count"]; $i=+10000){
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("Select * from table1 LIMIT 10000 OFFSET".$limit, array(
    PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL
    ));


    $limit =+ 10000;
}
```

Comment: A 500 error can be caused by various things. Find the error log and post the whole error here.

Comment: i tried debugging with `ini_set('display_error',1)` and also it is inside `try and catch` both didnt return any error. can you suggest a way to get the error? @OptimusCrime

Comment: Depends on your host and your system. Perhaps your host disallows you to overwirte the ini settings. I don't know for sure, but this question is very difficult to answer without knowing the actual error, not just the (extremely common) error code 500.

Comment: @OptimusCrime when there is error the `ini_set` work it is showing the error. Let me try again and be back

Comment: Are you using the same username/password to access both databases or not?

Comment: No I am using different username, password, PDO instance, dbname @YourCommonSense

Comment: @YourCommonSense when i put `LIMIT 10000` in the select it works well. could be that the server cant handle all `6639276` rows to be selected?

Comment: just run your code in loops, inserting 10000 at a time. but first of all you must get the particular error message. see https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors and also make sure your query is unbuffered, https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd

Comment: @YourCommonSense i already added the `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` got it from previous OP. As for `memory_get_usage()` will add it by the way this i tried looping I did will update can you criticize.

Comment: come on, you want to increment by 1 not by 10000?

Comment: and so, does it work now? if now, what is the error?

Comment: @YourCommonSense when i use `$i < $stmt1count_row["count"];` where `$stmt1count_row["count"] = total rows` I get 500 when I try using `50000` 500 error when I use `20000` it runs ok but the count I get is only `10000` only `10000` is inserted. Im still bedugging

Comment: I cant set the `MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` to false because I need to query in loop `While an unbufferered query is active, you cannot execute any other query. So, use this mode wisely.` @YourCommonSense

Comment: come on, you are running your query against ANOTHER connection. either way, it makes not sense to continue without the ACTUAL PHP error you get. Get to your apache error log and see it

Comment: @YourCommonSense if run now it was a mistake on part I didnt notice that the increment of limit was inside the while loop :) happy coding